# How to determine which language the current OS is running in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, lwjgl

I need to known in which language (or locale) the current OS is running.
Or, at least, in LWJGL. I have searched a lot, and do not found anything.

Comment: Have you tried the java Locale? Locale.getDefault() should be in the system's current language I suppose.

Comment: I use java.util.Locale.getDefault(), it work fine on desktop and android.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. It was so easy...

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Language like this:

```
java.util.Locale.getDefault().toString();
```

If you are looking or localizate your libgdx projects. This works wonders:

http://siondream.com/blog/games/internationalization-for-libgdx-projects/